# login with "su john" command does not source john's .bash_profile

Tags: bash, su

The `.bash_profile` for user john is not taking effect when I (as root) use the `su john` command to login as john. I have to use `source ~/.bash_profile` command every time I login as john using the `su john` command.

How can I automate this?

Thanks

Comment: I am using centOS 8

Answer (score 1):

From `man su`:

> **-, -l, --login**
>
> Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.
> When - is used, it must be specified before any username. For portability it is recommended to use it as last option, before any username. The other forms (-l and --login) do not have this restriction.

So to source john's `.bash_profile`, you should run `su -l john`.